# Docker Compose Failed to configure a DataSource in Spring Boot Microservices

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem about defining database in some services in my Spring Boot Microservice example.
When I run docker-compose.yml file through this command (docker-compose up -d), I have a datasource issue in **user service**, **advertisement service** and lastly **report service**.

All these services have their own **database** defined in their own **properties** file under configuration folder of **config server**.

Here is the **database** part of **docker-compose.yml**

```
database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "springbootuser"
      MYSQL_USER: "springmicroserviceuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "111111"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "111111"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "database"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
```

How can I fix the **datasource** issue in all **services** defined in docker-compose file

Here is my **docker-compose.yml** : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Here is the **user service properties** file : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations/user-service.properties)

Here is the **advertisement service properties** file : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations/advertisement-service.properties)

Here is the **report service properties** file : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/configserver/src/main/resources/configurations/report-service.properties)

Edited 1st :

Here is my new docker-compose.yml : [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OT_ENgnVoyx4Eon2jnZ9bmj8xGQLzvdn/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem with your datasource connection port `localhost:3306`.
user `3366` instead of `3306`.
when you define internal port on same docker network you need to use `database hostname` instead of `localhost`.
if you use localhost or IP then you need to use docker to expose a port for database connections that route from the external network.

if needed update docker compose database section:

```
ports:
 - "3366:3306"
expose:
 - "3366"
```

Comment: I editted my post.

Comment: change your data source properties  `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3366/springbootreport?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey` instead of `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootreport?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey`